# How to append html in jquery through assignment operator

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am working on Knockout.js

`<span data-bind="text: isNegotiable"></span>`

My jquery code is:

`self.isNegotiable = '<strike>Negotiable</strike>';`

How to execute this html tag in jquery as I cannot use .html() function here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [html binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html).

```
<span data-bind="html: isNegotiable"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `strike` always appears, you can move it inside the span: `<span><strike data-bind="text: isNegotiable"></strike></span>`.

Another option is to change the logic on `isNegotiable`, from string to boolean:

`self.isNegotiable(true or false)`

```
<!-- ko if: !isNegotiable -->
<span><strike>Negotiable</strike></span>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: isNegotiable -->
<span>Negotiable</span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

A third option is to create a [custom bindinghandler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). In this, you can use jQuery to create `html` nodes, based on certain logic (like if isNegotiable is true or false), but the last option (ko: if) is the simplest, in case you don't know how to create [custom bindinghandler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

Greetings

Comment: Hi I am using `<!-- Ko if: !isNegotiable -->
                <strike>Negotiable</strike>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- Ko if: isNegotiable -->
                <span>Negotiable</span>
                <!-- /ko -->` But it shows both Negotiable with strike and Negotiable??

Comment: The binding is ko if,  no Ko if.  Check http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html and assure isNegotiable is boolean. The text appears twice because knockout is not evaluating that html comment tags